# @html.DropDown ASP MVC and Select2 multiselect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have an `@Html.DropDownList` added to my view, the data for this dropdown is passed as a property in a ViewModel. How do I add Select2 Multiselect plugin onto this dropdownlist.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ValueId", new SelectList(item.Values, "Id", "Name"), new { @class = "values js-example-basic-multiple", @multiple ="multiple", @id="dropDown"}) | @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })`
```

JQuery:

```
$('#dropDown').select2();
```

After Page is Rendered:

```
 `<select class="values js-example-basic-multiple" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ValueId must be a number." data-val-required="The ValueId field is required." id="dropDown" multiple="multiple" name="ValueId"><option value="4">M</option>
```

8
Red
`

Scripts:

```
`<script src="/Content/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>`
```

`<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

`<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>`

UPDATE: I found the error. I was adding a new instance of JQuery to my page, and I forgot that my shared_layout page already has an instance of JQuery added.

Comment: That code should work. What is not working ?

Comment: Your code appeared completely correct. Are you sure that you are referencing the select2 library properly? What does the rendered markup for your `<select>` element look like? It could be that the ID isn't being set properly from the attribute. If that was the case, you would need to use `$('#ValueId').select2();`

Comment: the dropdownlist is generated but it is not the multiselect control with the search field and all the fancy stuff rather it is just a normal listbox

Comment: i checked the code after page is rendered as well the id and class is being set properly

Comment: Do you have any errors within your Developer Tools? Is the select2 library being loaded properly?

Comment: i guess you have a js error in your page which is preventing the bootstraping of the jQuery plugin

Comment: @HariGovind Welcome to [so]! Note that the system will automatically mark a question as solved when you accept an answer; you don't have to add it to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided, there are really two options :

- The jQuery library isn't being loaded or referenced.
- jQuery (or select2) aren't "ready" by the time they are called.

Since select2 depends on jQuery, you'll have to make sure that you are referencing it **and** that you are placing your necessary code within a document-ready block to ensure your dependencies are ready prior to being called :

```
<!-- Your Example List here -->
@Html.DropDownList("Foo", new SelectList(ViewBag.List), new { multiple = "true", id = "dropDown"})

<!-- Example references (prior to closing </body> tag) -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(function(){
          $('#dropDown').select2();
     });
</script>
```

You can [see a complete, and fully functional example using ASP.NET here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FfINkc).

Comment: there is no error in my Developer Console, i am calling Jquery first then select2.js

Comment: And you have it wrapped within the document-ready block similar to the example showed above? This also assumes that you don't have any other elements with the ID of "dropDown" in your page correct?

Comment: i have it inside the document ready block and there is no other control with that id.

Comment: Everything else looks correct. Your <select> element is being rendered correctly, your scripts are called within the correct order, and your actual select2.js code seems correct as well. I don't see anything else that it could cause it. Have you tried making a plain <select> element and using select2.js to target it? Just for testing purposes.

Comment: i tried it an its not loading that as well....i guess i have some issue with my bootstrap

Comment: Could you post an extended example with all of your markup? It might provide some insight as to exactly why this isn't working as expected.